# jQuery mobile, iterate elements (listview counter) and modify

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

How to iterate through all listview counters (find class ".ui-li-count") and change them dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".ui-li-count").each(function(i) {
    $(this).html(myArr[i]); //myArr has the correct numbers
});
```